Calculating Total of all Eth In & Out Across Three Chains
If I started the year with 35 ETH, should I not be able to calculate how much ETH I have now by adding up all of the Internal Transactions and Transactions where I received ETH, and then subtract the Out ETH + Gas? I just did this across three accounts and the result came to -24 ETH, which shouldn't be possible. Am I missing anything in the calculation?

You can probably use a https://transpose.io query to do this.
